# Get the portuguese language - Android

Tags: java, android

I've the following code, but there are only a few languages, and portuguese is not one of them, how it is possible to get the portuguese language?

```
if(Locale.ENGLISH.equals(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage())){

}
```

Comment: You could build it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html Or see http://www.localeplanet.com/java/pt-PT/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No guarantees this will work, but worth a shot.

Brazil and Portugal are the only countries I know of, sorry

```
List<String> ptLocales = Arrays.asList("pt_BR", "pt_PT");
if(ptLocales.contains(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage())){

}
```

Taken from http://www.localeplanet.com/java/

Comment: I'm not sure what your Locale.getDefault() returns

Answer (score 0):

Try this (mine is using thai) make a string.xml file for yourself that have all strings in portuguese[image]

```
public static void changeLocale(Context context, Locale locale) {
        Configuration conf = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = locale;
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
            conf.setLayoutDirection(conf.locale);
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

LocaleUtils.changeLocale(context, new Locale("th"));

Answer (score 0):

this is the list of portuguese locale

```
pt      Portuguese  português   
pt_AO   Portuguese (Angola) português (Angola)  
pt_BR   Portuguese (Brazil) português (Brasil)  Brazilian Portuguese
pt_GW   Portuguese (Guinea-Bissau)  português (Guiné Bissau)    
pt_MZ   Portuguese (Mozambique) português (Moçambique)  
pt_PT   Portuguese (Portugal)   português (Portugal)    Iberian Portuguese
pt_ST   Portuguese (São Tomé and Príncipe)  português (São Tomé e Príncipe)
```

just right click on values folder -> create values resources file

```
filename = strings.xml
directory name = values-pt
```

Source Code

this is how i do to set the locale

```
LanguageLocalHelper.setLocale(this,"pt");
```

then i use this wrapper class to change the locale setting

```
public class LanguageLocalHelper {

    public static void onCreate(Context context) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static void onCreate(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
        setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    }

    public static void setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        persist(context, language);
        updateResources(context, language);
    }

    private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(Constant.LANGUAGE_LOCALE, defaultLanguage);
    }

    private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(Constant.LANGUAGE_LOCALE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private static void updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration,null);
    }
}
```

for more info international ids.. look here [Local](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/)

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin you can use:

```
If (Locale.getDefault().language == "pt") {
....
}
```